# Open a post html response like form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

My server render a html file and send that while i send request by jquery post.

when i open string with `document.open(res)` it doesn't load javascript files and css files that aren't in html.
How can i open that like when submit form opens that?

```
$.post(url,data).done(function (res){
     //res contains html
});
```